# Is your boss allowed to have a meeting with you prior to your performance review without HR present

Tags: human-resources, review

My performance review is coming up. The way it works is the employee gets a self evaluation to fill out first, then we send it back to HR for review, then HR sends it to our Managers for their review then the manager sends it back to HR then we have a meeting with all three parties. My boss pulled me into her office prior to our meeting with all three parties involved because she wanted to have a meeting about my self evaluation then proceeded to tell me she was offended that I asked to learn parts of her job so I could be cross trained. My question is this: Is it against the law for her to pull me in her office prior to my review with hr so she could comment on my self evaluation? Doesn't HR have to be there? She was intimidating me because she didn't like what I said on my evaluation and I want to go to hr about it but not sure if I have a case so to speak or if it would just sound like I am complaining.

Comment: **Is it against the law for her to pull me in her office prior to my review with hr so she could comment on my self evaluation?** - It's probably not illegal, but you need to ask this on the appropriate site, or consult an attorney. This site isn't for legal question and I'd take any information here as anecdotal at best.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I appreciate it.

Comment: This is probably more a matter of company policy than law.

Comment: You should probably put some kind of a geography or nation tag on your question, since laws are different from place to place.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it against the law for her to pull me in her office prior to my review with hr so she could comment on my self evaluation?

That depends a lot on your location but in almost all cases this is perfectly legal

> Doesn't HR have to be there?

No. You can have 1:1 meetings with your boss without HR in the room.

> She was intimidating me because she didn't like what I said on my evaluation

This is fairly normal. Bosses will communicate if they don't like something.

> and I want to go to hr about it but not sure if I have a case so to speak or

Speak about what? That your boss is mean to you and you don't like it? What's the exact problem you are trying to solve here? HR only gets involved if there is a policy violation and that does not seem to be the case here.

> if it would just sound like I am complaining.

Yes.

Look, you should have an open discussion with your boss. Apparently you stepped on their toes, but not intentionally so. Talk it out. Ask her what specifically offended her and how she would like to manage your career growth.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the questions (Obligatory IANAL):

I cannot think of a scenario were this would be illegal. Is it improper? Possibly... even that is debatable. But illegal? I highly doubt it.

This is, unfortunately, a common issue with insecure management who are threatened by subordinates who show promise.

You could go to HR about this - given what you've described and reading between the lines, my intuition is that HR and Management probably get on fairly well and if you raise a complaint - your boss is going to start nit-picking everything you do in an effort to get you to leave.

Again - nothing illegal and nothing obvious enough to a legal claim.

My best advice is if this how your Boss has reacted - this won't be the first time or the last time - they feel threatened by you and they will sabotage and undermine you. It's never worth it working for someone like that - start job hunting.